# How pass object, contains computed property, to child?

Tags: vue.js

```
<template>
  child-component(
    v-for="item in items"
    :item="item"
  )
</template>

<script>
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      valueFromApi: null,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    someCompProp() { return val // math based on valueFromApi }
  },
  created: {
    setInterval(() => { // make api call and set valueFromApi }, 2000)
    this.createItems();
  },
  methods: {
    createItems() {
      // ...someActions
      formedItems.forEach((item) => {
        this.items.push({
          ...item,
          someValue: this.someCompProp,
        })
      })
      this.items.push(item)
    },
    apiCall() {
      // store result to valueFromApi
    }
</script>
```

Now it's not reactive.
I can achive reactivity only passing computed prop like independed property.
Can computed property `someCompProp` be reactive in child prop `item` obj?

Comment: You example missing some information. Where `val` comes from?

Comment: @Darius result of mathematical calculations based on valueFromApi, I changed code, added missing info

Comment: Okay, its done, i just return computed prop in someValue. `someValue: () => this.someCompProp,`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, its done, i just return computed prop in someValue. `someValue: () => this.someCompProp,`

Comment: computed property unnecessary here